# How to search for a value in one long string?

Tags: string, powershell, filter, select-string

I'm currently trying to filter a value from a long string I got by using a GET request with the `cURL` command. The output looks like this:

```
{"errors":null,"result":{"host_id":"1632","display_name":"notshownhere","hostname":"notshownhere","dnsname":"","ip":"1.1.1.1","host_type_id":"1","checks":[{"check_id":"12851","preset_id":"1","checktype_id":"1","checktype_short_name":"ping","status":"3","status_condition":"ok","status_color":"green","status_change_time":"1589066121","result_short":"1.1.1.1 is alive","result_time":"1591683892"}
```

My aim is to filter out the `host_id` from this output. This means, I want to find a way how I can only output the `host_id` with the number `1632`.

I tried out `Select-String`, but it didn't work because the string is too long.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like JSON and it would be best to use ConvertFrom-Json command on a proper JSON. That results in a PowerShell object where you could use `object.'host_id'` to retrieve the value.

Parsing the string, you can do the following.

```
# Assuming $j contains your string
($j | Select-String -Pattern '(?<="host_id":")\d+(?=")').Matches.Value
```

Since `-pattern` by default take a regex string, `(?<=)` contains a positive lookbehind from the current position. `(?=)` is a positive lookahead. `\d+` is one or more digits. Since the command returns a `MatchInfo` object, you need to access the `Value` to return the digits.